# How to create and work with array of instance in c++?

Tags: c++

So i created a class named box which has private property of width, height and depth. and has setters and getters for these properties. Now, I want to create a array of this box objects and set them the width height and depth. I tried following code but does not work.
EDIT: volume() method just calculates and returns volume.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Box.h"
using namespace std;

int main(){
int numbox;
cout << "Enter the number of boxes that you want : ";
cin >> numbox;
cout<<endl;
//dynamic array of boxes
Box * pnt;
pnt = new Box [numbox];
//setting the properties
double height, width, depth;
for (int i = 0; i<numbox;i++){
    //keyboard inputs
    cout<<"Height of box no."<<i+1<<" = ";
    cin >> height
    cout<<"widht of box no."<<i+1<<" = ";
    cin >> width
    cout<<"Height of box no."<<i+1<<" = ";
    cin >> depth
    //setting the properties for instances
    pnt[i].setheight(height);
    pnt[i].setwidth(width);
    pnt[i].setdepth(depth);
            pnt[i].print();
}

double vol, sumvol;
for (int j = 0; j < numbox; j++){
    //calculate volume
    vol = pnt[i].volume();
    cout<<"Volume of box no. "<<j+1<< " = "<<vol<<endl;
    sumvol = sumvol + vol;
}
cout << "Total volume of all boxes = " << sumvol <<endl;
return 0;
return 0;

}
```

Error/warning I get is :

```
testbox.cpp:42:13: note: (if you use '-fpermissive' G++ will accept your code)
```

line 42: vol = pnt[i].volume();

The program works fine till printing the boxes bot terminates on calculating volume.

Comment: When you say "does not work", what do you mean by that? Can you elaborate? Do you get compiler errors? Linker errors? Runtime errors? Something else? For compiler and linker errors, please edit the question to include the complete and unedited error log. For runtime errors, please try running your program in a debuggers, and at least edit your question to include the function callstack.

Comment: You might also want to look into [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: I get warning with 

'if you use -fpermissive' G++ will accept your code'

in the line with vol = pnt[i].volume();

Comment: Please edit your question to include the *complete* error log. Including line numbers and any other messages. Because that isn't the complete message. It doesn't say anything about the *actual* error, for example.

Comment: I got the error finally :)
it was so stupid of me. I have on loop int j as counter and on pointer i have kept 'i', in the loop for calculating volume. thank you for all your replies. fixed it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a vector instead of arrays and avoid using dynamic allocation when possible. create a vector of Boxes.

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<Box> boxes;
```

For the number of boxes, create a new box and add to vector

```
for (int i = 0; i<numbox;i++){

    Box box_;
    //keyboard inputs
    cout<<"Height of box no."<<i+1<<" = ";
    cin >> height;
    cout<<"widht of box no."<<i+1<<" = ";
    cin >> width;
    cout<<"Height of box no."<<i+1<<" = ";
    cin >> depth;
    //setting the properties for instances
    box_.setheight(height);
    box_.setwidth(width);
    box_.setdepth(depth);
            box_.print();

    boxes.push_back(box_);
}
```

this alongside fixed issues with missing `;` after cin should work

Comment: However, my task is to work with dynamic allocation so I cannot use vector for now

Comment: @jason Fair enough but you should state that in the question. Ideally however you should use vector and should tell your lecturer/professor etc to use them to ;)

Comment: :) haha i will tell her in next lecture :) or write a note in the code :) 
thank you for your reply. fixed the problem finally. it was stupid. in second loop i was using 'j' as counter and kept 'i' for pointer allocation :D

Answer (score 2):

`;` is missed here in all `cin` which could lead to compile time errors,

`cin >> height`

Comment: got the error :) fixed it. 
It was the counter in the loop for the calculating volume. 
I had int j as counter and i was using 'i' for pointer allocation.